# Errorwhen installing Composer: The PHP exe file you specified did not execute correctly

Tags: php, composer-php, wampserver

When I try to open wampserver, I get the following error:

```
php-win.exe - Application Error

The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). 
Click OK to close the application.
```

Then I click OK, and then wampserver boots up, and everything works fine.

The only problem is that I can't install composer because I get the following error:

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not execute correctly: 
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe
```

Running it from the command line might highlight the problem.

```
Internal Error [ERR_STATUS], exit code -1073741701
```

Comment: did you try to run it from command line?

Comment: You use the command line and the PHP CLI ( Command Line Interface ) to install Composer on windows. Also use php.exe rather than php-win.exe

Answer (score 1):

If you have the XDebug extension,comment it.

#### php.ini:

```
;extension=php_xdebug.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I am trying to install Composer on xampp using windows installer:

**Solution**:
I commented `allow_call_time_pass_reference` variable in php.ini file and also I changed value of `allow_url_fopen=On`

Then you have to restart the Apache Server.
Try to install Composer once again.
Then close all the current application and log off.
Then check it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error and finally I have fixed it. Please make sure that the following extensions are disabled in your php.ini. See example given below;

```
[CLDbg]
;extension=php_cl_dbg_5_1.dll
;clport=6000
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error because I tried to use it with PHP 7.3 - which at the time of writing doesn't seem possible.

Rolled back to 7.2 and its fine.